# Sharing a file through my ios Application with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, file-sharing

I have some files that want to share with any application. I use this code

```
var fileDAta = NSData.FromFile(path);

UIActivityViewController activityViewController = new UIActivityViewController
                        (new NSObject[]{ fileDAta }, null); //(items, null);

PresentViewController(activityViewController,true,null);
```

[image]

As you see, it should be more application but as a default, there is just the Mail App. it is the same for real device.. (I also installed Gmail and Outlook but there is not on the list or on the more list)

Anyway,when i select the Mail, it cannot be attached ..

[image]

What I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the following code for sharing but remember respective applications(gmail,twitter etc) for sharing must be installed on your device and configured.

```
 UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems: fileDAta applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]; //or whichever you don't need
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i would like to share with other apps like MS word, ms outlook, X, Y .....  I think it is about fileDAta type. I tried NSUrl, NSString... but its the same..